# A nice sequence of random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $f:U\mapsto \mathbb{R}^k$ with $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth injective 
function. Suppose that $\sqrt n(Y_n- Y)\to N(0,\Omega)$ in distribution with $Y=f(X)$. Define  $X_n$ by $X_n=\operatorname{arg}\min_{x\in U}\|f(x)-Y_n\|$ for all $n\geq 1$.

I'd like to know the relation between $X_n$ and $X$. What I know is only 
\begin{equation}
\|f(X_n)-Y_n\|\leq \|f(X)-Y_n\|=\|Y_n-Y\|=O_p(1/\sqrt n).
\end{equation}
However I am stacked here. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if argmin is non unique, for example because $f$ is not one-to-one?

Comment: Thanks @Did for your comment. OK, I've added $f$ is injective. Thanks for your correction

Comment: i think these kinds of estimators are known as extremum estimators. Wikipeida has a (not so good) page on them (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremum_estimator)

Comment: Thanks @user103828 for your suggestion. I'll have a look the given link